# A TextView is hiding behind a Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a RelativeLayout to show a carticon with a TextView (count) in our xml.

Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:id="@+id/showevents"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/cart"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/showevents"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/showevents"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I show the TextView (at the right side) just above the button? 
Now our TextView is showing behind the cart icon.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Including screenshots and explanations of what you tried so far would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/showevents"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/showevents"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="65dip"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:id="@+id/showevents"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:background="@drawable/cart"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way..and it shows perfectly

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/carticon"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/relcarts"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="19dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cart_counter_bg"
                android:text="0"
                android:id="@+id/cartcountrs"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dip"
        android:layout_height="65dip"
        android:id="@+id/showevents"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@drawable/cart"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/showevents"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/showevents"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I simply replaced `android:layout_alignTop="@id/showevents"` with `android:layout_above="@id/showevents"`